# Mostrar los datos de un API en código HTML usando AXIOS y NodeJ

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, axios

Estoy tratando de mostrar estos datos que es el `TITULO`, `EXTRACTO` y la `IMAGEN` del API en forma de HTML.

[image: Esta es la API]

Pero no encuentro una manera de que se vean, me aparece el error de `UNDEFINED` o no funciona el `forEach`.

Este es el código en HTML:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('json_get');
    boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      axios.get('https://conectate.um.edu.mx/categoria/feed/mental', {
        responseType: 'json'
      })
        .then(function(res) {
          if(res.status==200) {
            console.log("RESPUESTA", res.data);
            let articulos = '';
            res.data.forEach(articulo => {
              articulos += `
                <div class="articulos-titulo">
                  <h3 class="titulo">${articulo.TITULO}</h3>
                  <h3 class="descripcion">${articulo.EXTRACTO}</h3>
                  <img src="${articulo.IMAGEN}" alt="">
                </div>
                      `;
                  });
            if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
                      document.getElementById('articulosEjemplo').innerHTML = articulos;
                  }
          }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .then(function() {
          loading.style.display = 'none';
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="articulosEjemplo" id="articulosEjemplo">
  <button id="carga_ajax">Carga contenido</button> 
  <button id="json_get">Request JSON GET</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo correcto es `res.data.data.forEach`.

Más info: [Axios > Esquema de Respuesta](https://axios-http.com/es/docs/res_schema)

#### Demo:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('json_get');
boton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  axios.get('https://conectate.um.edu.mx/categoria/feed/mental', {
      responseType: 'json'
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        console.log("RESPUESTA", res.data);
        let articulos = '';
        res.data.data.forEach(articulo => {
          articulos += `
                <div class="articulos-titulo">
                  <h3 class="titulo">${articulo.TITULO}</h3>
                  <h3 class="descripcion">${articulo.EXTRACTO}</h3>
                  <img src="${articulo.IMAGEN}" alt="">
                </div>
                      `;
        });
        if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
          document.getElementById('articulosEjemplo').innerHTML = articulos;
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .then(function() {
      loading.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-uMtXmF28A2Ab/JJO2t/vYhlaa/3ahUOgj1Zf27M5rOo8/+fcTUVH0/E0ll68njmjrLqOBjXM3V9NiPFL5ywWPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="articulosEjemplo" id="articulosEjemplo">
  <button id="carga_ajax">Carga contenido</button>
  <button id="json_get">Request JSON GET</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias bro, si era justo eso, ya me estaba desesperando porque no encontraba la solución